# Receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS with SDL_Event* in C++

Tags: c++, events, sdl, exc-bad-access

I've read many(MANY!) `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` examples but non of the solutions provided seems to be working for the issue I have. Basically, I have a gameloop that looks like this:

```
int GameEngine::Run()
{

    if( this->OnInit() == false )
        return -1;

    SDL_Event Event;

    while( this->IsRunning )
    {

        while( SDL_PollEvent( &Event ) )
        {

            INPUT->Event( &Event );
            for( int i = 0; i < this->objects.size(); i++ )
            {

                this->objects[i]->OnEvent();

            }

            if( INPUT->Type( SDL_QUIT ) )
               this->Stop();

        }

        this->OnLoop();
        this->OnRender();

    }

    this->OnCleanUp();

    this->PrintObjects();

    return 0;

}
```

It is most likely the

```
INPUT->Event( &Event );
```

that is causing the trouble. This function looks like this in the `Input` class:

```
void Input::Event( SDL_Event* CurrEvent ) { this->Current_Event = CurrEvent; }
```

(*This is also the line that gives me the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`*)

So `this->Current_Event` in Input class will always contain the current event since it will be updated from the game loop with the event that was the latest to be polled.

Currently I don't know how to get the stacktrace in Xcode but if I do some manual trace it goes like the following:

```
Input::Event()
GameEngine::Run()
main()
```

And then it goes into SDL code.

Does anyone know what might be the problem here? Tell me if you need to know anything else!

Comment: Could you please show us where INPUT is declared and initialized?

Comment: That's it! Apparently I had not initialized INPUT, only declared it :) Thanks for the help dauphic!

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is saying is that you did something that caused a pointer (yours, one internal to your device, or one that the allocator is using) to be dereferenced and that memory location isn’t inside one of the chunks assigned to your program.

with `SDL_Event*` here, it is raised because `INPUT` is not initialized.